# Send ref via props in functional component

Tags: reactjs, react-native, ref, use-ref

In my parent component I call hook useRef: `const flatListRef = useRef(null);`  and then I want to use this `flatListRef` in child component. I tried to do like in [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactforwardref) but without success. When I call my function toTop I get: `null is not an object (evaluating 'flatListRef.current.scrollToOffset')`

This is my parent component:

```
const BeautifulPlacesCards = ({navigation}: HomeNavigationProps<"BeautifulPlacesCards">) => {
    const flatListRef = useRef(null);
    const toTop = () => {
        flatListRef.current.scrollToOffset(1)
    }
    const buttonPressed = () => {
     toTop()
    }
    return(
           <Carousel filteredData={filteredData} flatListRef={flatListRef}/>
    )
}
```

This is my child component:

```
const Carousel = forwardRef((filteredData, flatListRef) => {
 return (
         <AnimatedFlatList 
                  ref={flatListRef}
         />
 )
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a working example: https://snack.expo.dev/@zvona/forwardref-example

Key takes:

- you need to use prop `ref` when passing it down, not `flatListRef`
- you need to destructure `filteredData` from props

Here is the relevant code:

```
const Child = forwardRef(({ filteredData }, ref) => {
  return (
    <FlatList
      ref={ref}
      style={styles.flatList}
      data={filteredData}
      renderItem={({ item }) => (
        <Text style={styles.item} key={`foo-${item}`}>
          {item}
        </Text>
      )}
    />
  );
});

const App = () => {
  const flatListRef = useRef(null);

  const toTop = () => {
    flatListRef.current.scrollToOffset(1);
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Button title={'Scroll back'} onPress={toTop} />
      <Child filteredData={[1,2,3,4,5,6]} ref={flatListRef} />
    </View>
  );
};
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I changed `flatListRef` to `ref` and now it works!